# Mp4 not autoplaying in Chrome, working fine in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, mp4, autoplay

Here is the live site: nonbinaryassembly.com

And here is my code:

```
<video id='second_slider_image' autoplay loop width="100%" alt='second_slider_image'>
        <source src="http://nonbinaryassembly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/000652895-aerial-view-city-skyscrapers.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In Chrome, unless you have only one tab open, do you have this video in a background tab or does this refusal to autoplay happen when it is in the foreground tab too?

Answer (score 0):

I think in Chrome you have to set it as autoplay=true. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried every combination I could.  It wasn't working on other people's machines either.  Maybe the video was too large - I tried reducing the size but it loaded fine so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out why it wasn't running properly (I ended up removing autoplay so it's not in there anymore), so I came up and an OK solution using JS:

```html
<video id="USTC" width="100%" src="http://URL/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4' onmouseenter="play_if_stopped();" onended="slider_run();">
```

```js
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("uniqueID");
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
    get: function(){
        return (!this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
    }
});

function play_if_stopped() {
  if(document.querySelector('#uniqueID').playing){ // checks if element is playing right   now
    console.log("playing");
  } else {
    videoPlayer.play();
    console.log("started");
  }
};


function slider_run(){
  video_count++;
  if (video_count == 3) video_count =1;
  var nextVideo = "http://URL/"+video_count+".mp4";
  videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
  videoPlayer.play();
};
```